# Sumifs between two numbers across different dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I have two data frames. One with a "from" and "to" intervals as follows;

```
Intervals <- data.frame("From" = c(0.0000,0.0069,0.0139,0.0208,0.0278,0.0347,0.0417,0.0486,0.0556,0.0625,0.0694,0.0764,0.0833),
                        "To" = c(0.0410,0.0479,0.0549,0.0618,0.0688,0.0757,0.0826,0.0896,0.0965,0.1035,0.1104,0.1174,0.1243))
```

and the second data frame is:

```
x <- data.frame("Dummy" = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), 
                "Dummy Time" = c(0,0,0.006944444,0.006944444,0.010416667,0.010416667,0.013888889,0.013888889,0.020833333,0.024305556,0.027777778,0.03125,0.03125))
```

So I basically want to do a sumifs in R of the dummy variable if the dummy time falls between the From and To (or equal to) in the interval df. This is easy in excel but im pretty new to R.

Thanks

Comment: If it helps, you should merged the two `data.frame()` s together with `cbind()`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

cbind(Intervals, x)%>%
data.frame()%>%
rowwise()%>%
filter(between(Dummy_Time, From, To))%>%
.$Dummy%>%
sum()
```

should do the job. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks but the cbind wont work because Intervals and x are different rows. Basically the intervals are just the standard day and I'm hoping to create a new column on intervals to show the sum of dummys that incur during  that time period